# Why dont float?

Tags: html, css

Why aren't the two boxes floating side-by-side in the following code?

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .box1{
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background: purple;
        float:left;
    }

    .box2{
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background: yellow;
    }
    </style>

    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Chead/vCMJE/) describing question.

Comment: Your jsfiddle link is not correct :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `float` css property removes the element from the regular flow of the page.  This means that its position will not be affected by other elements (which are not also floating).  For this reason, in your example, the two elements end up on top of each other.

If you assign `.box2` the property `float:left` as well, they will sit next to each other, as I believe you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Just a Small Change:

```
.box2{
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background: yellow;
float:left;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vCMJE/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Will and Jatin are correct but you can also try wrapping both the div`s in a single wrapper div and display both the divs in the same line

Example:

```
 .container
 {
     display:inline-block;
 }

.box1{
    width:50px;
    height:200px;
    background: purple;
    float:left; 
 }

.box2{
    width: 50px;
    height:200px;
    background: yellow;
    float:right;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Chead/vCMJE/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:

1) Wrap the two boxes in a div

2) Add float:left to both the boxes

In this way  you need not clear the float for subsequent containers